# What can I add to a catch statement to show the properties that caused an error?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a web service that uses this 3rd party call(`geoLock.AdjustSensorsAsync`) to create an object.

When it works, it works fine. Here it is:

```
geologicalEvent.LocationName = geologicalEvent.LocationName;
try
{
    sensorResult = await geoLock.AdjustSensorsAsync(
        geologicalEvent.LocationId,
        geologicalEvent.LocationName,
        geologicalEvent.LocationStart.ToUniversalTime(),
        geologicalEvent.LocationEnd.ToUniversalTime()
        );
} catch
{

}
```

But sometimes a bad `LocationStart` or `LocationEnd` is passed to it and I'll get an error like:

`FaultException: "Unable to record. Invalid time."`

Right now, it just shows the line number of the error, but I'd like to see more detailed info on what entity caused the error.

What can I add to the `catch` to show which specific `LocationId` and also the 'LocationStart' and 'LocationEnd' that caused it?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want "more info"? There's not more you can do except the linenumber unless you wrap every statement into a try-catch-block.

Comment: You have access to the `geologicalEvent` variable inside the `catch` block.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain thanks, I was wondering about that, but I was trying to get more info.  Thanks!

Comment: @gunr2171 but can I just write that out to the browser?  thanks

Comment: "to the browser"? You have access to the variable in the catch. Do whatever you want to with it. I don't know how you're moving data to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the catch block for the specific exception type and encapsulate it in your own exception with the desired information. Something like this:

```
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{ex.Message} LocationStart: {geologicalEvent.LocationStart} LocationEnd: {geologicalEvent.LocationEnd}", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
geologicalEvent.LocationName = geologicalEvent.LocationName;

try
{
    sensorResult = await geoLock.AdjustSensorsAsync(
    geologicalEvent.LocationId,
    geologicalEvent.LocationName,
    geologicalEvent.LocationStart.ToUniversalTime(),
    geologicalEvent.LocationEnd.ToUniversalTime()
    );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}
```

Something like that maybe? Using the 'catch (Exception e)' to do a console writeline and see what it spits out.

Reference: [Microsoft documentation - try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)